# Spring boot keeps interrupting the running cronjob tasks despite being configured to wait for them before shutting down

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduling, spring-scheduled

In my sping boot application i have several Cron jobs that should be able to finish running before the application shuts down. I'm using a `TaskSchedulerCustomizer` bean to configure spring's default task scheduler to wait for tasks to complete on shutdown.

```
@Bean //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664259/spring-scheduled-task-graceful-shutdown
public TaskSchedulerCustomizer taskSchedulerCustomizer() { //Dit laat Spring het TaskScheduler object zelf aanmaken en customized het alleen.
    return taskScheduler -> {
        taskScheduler.setPoolSize(CORE_THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
        taskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("CronJob-");
        taskScheduler.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        taskScheduler.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(AWAIT_TERMINATION_SECONDS);
    };
}
```

Despite setting `setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown()` to `true` the graceful shutdown of Spring boot still interrupts my running cronjob tasks. I've also added the following settings to my `application.properties`:

```
spring.task.scheduling.shutdown.await-termination=true
spring.task.scheduling.shutdown.await-termination-period=30s
spring.task.execution.shutdown.await-termination=true
spring.task.execution.shutdown.await-termination-period=30s
```

But these are all ignored as well. I also called `initialize()` on the `taskScheduler` in after setting `setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown()` to true to see if that would help. But didn't help either.

So i've pretty much tried everything to get spring to respect my running cronjob tasks. Is there anything left i could try?

Here's the cronjob code that i used for testing

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * *")
public void schedule() throws InterruptedException {
    log.info("starting dummy scheduler");

    Thread.sleep(10000);
    log.info("ending dummy scheduler");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem by looking at the code snippets from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63346374/how-to-configure-graceful-shutdown-using-delegatingsecuritycontextscheduledexecu?rq=2).

When I create my own `TaskScheduler` bean and then register it using the overidden `configureTasks` method of an `SchedulingConfigurer` implementation everything works. Its very strange that it only works this way and not with a `TaskSchedulerCustomizer` bean or with the aforementioned application.properties properties. Heres the code:

```
@EnableScheduling
public class ContextSchedulingConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(securitytaskScheduler());
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler= new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(120);
        taskScheduler.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        taskScheduler.setPoolSize(2);
        taskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("XXXXXXXXX");
        return taskScheduler;
    }
}
```

Its a paste from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63346374/how-to-configure-graceful-shutdown-using-delegatingsecuritycontextscheduledexecu?rq=2)